# Resize tableView when device is rotated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, resize, tableview

I have an issue with my application when rotating the device. The tableView extends over the devices view causing it to be unaccessable.

How can I get the table to resize so this wouldn't happen?

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"Device is rotated sidewise");

        myTable.delegate = self;
        myTable.dataSource = self;
        myTable.scrollEnabled = YES;

        [self.view addSubview:myTable];

        myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 148, 320, 10)];
    }
}
```

I am a complete noob when it comes to coding with xcode or objective-c. I am currently studying this, so please be noob friendly with your answers.

Comment: google `autolayout` or `viewresizing masks` in iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Autoresizing mask and don't set frame on orientation.Use below link to understand about autoresizing.With autoresizing you don't need to code anything programmatically.
http://www.techpaa.com/2012/05/understanding-uiview-autoresizing.html

Answer (score 1):

If Autolayout is turned off then your autoresizemask should look like this

[image: Autosizing masks needs to adjusted as per pic]

Answer (score -1):

You can use autolayout if you are adding a tableview through interface builder

If you need to do it programmatically then change your code as follows

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"Device is rotated sidewise");
        myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 148, 320, 10)];
        myTable.delegate = self;
        myTable.dataSource = self;
        myTable.scrollEnabled = YES;

        [self.view addSubview:myTable];


    }
}
```